# How to make image zoomable in Xamarin.Android?

Tags: xamarin.android, zooming

I have the following image:

[image]

Its dimensions are `1920 X 1901 pixels`. On the following link is its real dimension:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/0rjdP.jpg

I want it to occupy all the space of the screen bellow the `toolbar` but as it's that big when I put the image in the screen and run the application, when I try to go to the `activity` the image is in, I got an exception. Apart from wanting to make the image occupy the whole space bellow the toolbar I want when I make the gestures spread and pinch, the image to zoom in and to zoom out respectively.

P.S. I run the application on 5 inches device, but I'm planning to run it on bigger and smaller devices too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Xamarin Android ,you can custom **[Touch](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/app-fundamentals/touch/touch-in-android#gestures)** event of ImageView to implement it .

**Xml** : Adding a ImageView with a sample image :

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/main_imgZooming"
        android:background="@color/accent_material_dark"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:scaleType="matrix"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:src="@drawable/imageone"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Then in **Activity** , you can custom the Touch Event :

```
public class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity
{
    private ImageView view;

    private static  int NONE = 0;
    private static  int DRAG = 1;
    private static  int ZOOM = 2;

    private int mode = NONE;
    private float oldDist;
    private Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
    private Matrix savedMatrix = new Matrix();
    private PointF start = new PointF();
    private PointF mid = new PointF();

    float minScaleR = 0.1f;  //Minimum scaling
    static  float MAX_SCALE = 4f; //Maximum zoom ratio
    //float dist = 1f;

    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);
        Xamarin.Essentials.Platform.Init(this, savedInstanceState);
        // Set our view from the "main" layout resource
        SetContentView(Resource.Layout.activity_main);

        /*
        view = FindViewById<ImageView>(Resource.Id.main_imgZooming);
        view.Touch += Img_test_Touch;

        matrix.SetScale(minScaleR, minScaleR); //Start zooming out first

        var metrics = Resources.DisplayMetrics;
        int screenWidth = metrics.WidthPixels;

        matrix.PostTranslate(screenWidth / 4, screenWidth / 2);     //The position of the image is offset by screenWidth/2 pixels from the top left corner of the imageview
        view.ImageMatrix = matrix;
        */
    }

    // calculator the distance of two points
    private float distance(MotionEvent eventA)
    {
        float x = eventA.GetX(0) - eventA.GetX(1);
        float y = eventA.GetY(0) - eventA.GetY(1);
        return (float)(System.Math.Sqrt(x * x + y * y));
    }

    // calculator the middle point of two points
    private PointF middle(MotionEvent eventB)
    {
        float x = eventB.GetX(0) + eventB.GetX(1);
        float y = eventB.GetY(0) + eventB.GetY(1);
        return new PointF(x / 2, y / 2);
    }


    private void Img_test_Touch(object sender, Android.Views.View.TouchEventArgs e)
    {
        ImageView view = sender as ImageView;
        switch (e.Event.Action & e.Event.ActionMasked)
        {
            //single finger
            case MotionEventActions.Down:
                //matrix.Set(view.Matrix);
                savedMatrix.Set(matrix);
                start.Set(e.Event.GetX(), e.Event.GetY());
                mode = DRAG;
                Console.WriteLine(mode +"---"+ e.Event.GetX());
            break;

            //double finger
            case MotionEventActions.PointerDown:
                oldDist = distance(e.Event);
                if (oldDist > 10f)
                {
                    savedMatrix.Set(matrix);
                    middle(e.Event);
                    mode = ZOOM;
                }
                Console.WriteLine(mode+"---" + oldDist);
             break;
            //finger up
            case MotionEventActions.Up:
            case MotionEventActions.PointerUp:
                mode = NONE;
                break;
            // finger move
            case MotionEventActions.Move:
                if (mode == DRAG)
                {
                    //single finger
                    matrix.Set(savedMatrix);
                    matrix.PostTranslate(e.Event.GetX() - start.X, e.Event.GetY() - start.Y);
                } else if (mode == ZOOM) {
                    //double finger
                    float newDist = distance(e.Event);
                    if (newDist > 10f) {
                        matrix.Set(savedMatrix);
                        float scale = newDist / oldDist;
                        matrix.PostScale(scale, scale, mid.X, mid.Y);
                    }
            }
            break;
        }

        view.ImageMatrix = matrix;
        CheckScale();  //Limit zoom range
        center();
    }

    //Limit maximum and minimum scaling
    protected void CheckScale()
    {
        float[] p = new float[9];
        matrix.GetValues(p);
        if (mode == ZOOM)
        {
            if (p[0] < minScaleR)
            {
                matrix.SetScale(minScaleR, minScaleR);
            }
            if (p[0] > MAX_SCALE)
            {
                matrix.Set(savedMatrix);
            }
        }
    }


    //Automatic centering
    protected void center()
    {
        center(true, true);
    }

    private void center(bool horizontal, bool vertical)
    {
        Matrix m = new Matrix();
        m.Set(matrix);
        Drawable d = GetDrawable(Resource.Drawable.imageone);
        //Get image width and height
        int imgWidth = d.IntrinsicWidth;
        int imgHeight = d.IntrinsicHeight;


        RectF rect = new RectF(0, 0, imgWidth, imgHeight);
        m.MapRect(rect);
        float height = rect.Height();
        float width = rect.Width();
        float deltaX = 0, deltaY = 0;

        var metrics = Resources.DisplayMetrics;

        if (vertical)
        {

            int screenHeight = metrics.HeightPixels;
            //Phone screen resolution height

            if (height < screenHeight)
            {
                deltaY = (screenHeight - height) / 2 - rect.Top;
            }
            else if (rect.Top > 0)
            {
                deltaY = -rect.Top;
            }
            else if (rect.Bottom < screenHeight)
            {
                deltaY = view.Height - rect.Bottom;
            }
        }

        if (horizontal)
        {
            //Phone screen resolution width
            int screenWidth = metrics.WidthPixels;

            if (width < screenWidth)
            {
                deltaX = (screenWidth - width) / 2 - rect.Left;
            }
            else if (rect.Left > 0)
            {
                deltaX = -rect.Left;
            }
            else if (rect.Right < screenWidth)
            {
                deltaX = screenWidth - rect.Right;
            }
        }
        matrix.PostTranslate(deltaX, deltaY);
    }
}
```

The effect as follow :

[image]

Comment: I had to remove `case MotionEventActions.Down` from the `Img_test_Touch` method because after zooming in or out when I move away my two fingers from the screen and bring them closer again and touch the screen with them, the image takes its original dimensions and I don't want that, I want the image to change size only if I have made the gestures spread and pinch. I have a question . Although I have set `layout_width` and `layout_height` ot the `ImageView` to `match_parent` , the image doesn't ocuppy the whole screen. How to fix that?

Comment: @Montoolivo I have updated answer , you can have a look when you have time .

Comment: With the new code, the image doesn't occupy the whole screen but is in the center and looks very small furthermore it doesn't do the zooming as smoothly as the previous code.

Comment: @Montoolivo Hi , there are somewhere to optimize . But about  *the image doesn't occupy the whole screen but is in the center and looks very small* because I set to  the small scale as follow code :  `matrix.SetScale(minScaleR, minScaleR); //Start zooming out first` .Just want to show the whole Image , you can canel it .About smoothly , I will check it . If other good optimization , will update here.

Comment: @Montoolivo I have updated answer . About not fitting parent ,it result from `android:scaleType` set the `matrix` . If answer be helpful , you can mark it or vote up when you have time . Later I will optimize it , you also can improve it based on code of answer  :)

Comment: Do you think I can move all the code responsible for the zooming and the image occupying all the screen in another class and call it in the `activity` , so that my `activity` looks more clean and also to reuse the zooming functionality in another activity? If it's possible can you show me how to do it?

Comment: @Montoolivo It's possible . You can custom a ImageView with zooming function , when used just invoke it .Sorry for not having this sample now. Later if have will update here .